# How can I get the information from a column next to the active cell to be included in the email?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this script running which works fine. However as you see, it only copies the information of the active cell in Column 10 `toString`. How can I get the information next to it in Column 11 to be included in the email? I've tried numerous options without luck.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if(sheet.getName()=='Dispatch Log'){
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var cellcol = cell.getColumn();
      if(cellcol == 10){
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "tor@domain.com";
  var subject = 'Pickup Requested '+cellvalue;
  var body = 'A new Pickup has been placed for ' + cellvalue + '. Please coordinate with dispatch.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Use offset, for details see the docs on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range. If you need further help please add more details about your search/research efforts.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what you want, but you can try to change from:

```
var cellcol = cell.getColumn();
```

to:

```
var cellcol = cell.getLastColumn();
```